# Do I have to create an app using the original Instagram API before i can use the instagram graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I'm trying to create an app with the new Graph API for instagram business accounts.

I am following the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started)

It says after adding Facebook login, I need to submit the app for review to be able to use the api, and I need to create a screencast on how the app will be used.

Am I looking at the wrong documentation? How am I suppose to create the app without being able to pull any data from the API?

Is there no sandbox mode until the app is developed that I can use?

Do I have to create an app using the Instagram API first to be able to request permissions to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new instagram graph API is an extension of the existing Facebook API.

So you can make requests on the new API by have a facebook login on your app, then requesting access for the users pages and the users instagram data.

Once you are able to access their pages data you can [submit a `get` request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/page) and fetch `?fields=instagram_business_account`

once you get the instagram accounts ID, you can make requests on it following this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/)

In development you can only access your own pages, once you build using your own data then you can submit your app for permissions, and finally you can submit your app for review.

Comment: Hey @RickS, did you need to submit a screencast with Instagram Login? I have Facebook Login in my app so I assume Instagram Login is not needed? Also I don't think IG login exists anymore?

Comment: @Danny no, you're going to have to submit a screencast of how your app uses their api, alongside a screencast you will need to explain it to them. They most likely wont bother checking your app yourself usually they will just base their decision off the screencast. For my app a lot is backend stuff so i had to explain it in text.

Answer (score 2):

While I haven’t had any experience in Instagram apps, I do have a bit of Graph API experience with Facebook

While in development (a switch at the top of the App Dashboard), any developers and administrators can test the app using any and all permissions. To make the app public however you need to submit for review.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i was confused because i thought that the new instagram graph API was separate from the Facebook graph api, but its the same API and i need access from the users Facebook account.